# SMSS v17 Stored Proc to insert rows into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, sql-insert

I have two tables: PS_Emp and PS_SAR_General

The stored procedure should update PS_SAR_General with any Employee IDs that don't exist in that table from PS_Emp. Could you let me know where I've gone wrong?

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SAR_NewEmp_app]
@USID
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.PS_SAR_General ([USID])
VALUES (@USID)


FROM dbo.PS_Emp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PS_Emp.[USID] FROM PS_Emp WHERE PS_SAR_General 
[USID] = PS_Emp.[USID]) AND PS_Emp.[Status] = 'Active' AND 
PS_Emp.[ECS ICS] = 'ECS' AND PS_Emp.[Employee Class] NOT IN 
('BRWDRESORCE', 'SUBCONTRACT')
```

Comment: If you want to insert with values from a table you use `insert into XXX () select YYY from` i.e. you don't use the `values` keyword.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You description says "update", but you don't have any "update" statements in the code. You need to use "UPDATE" statement to change existing rows.

Comment: I'm just really confused by your answers. I'm very new at this and just learning. Could you provide an example or show me how to fix the code?

Comment: The link above is to the official documentation which shows how to construct an insert statement. There are loads of examples there to help...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for an answer here is what ended up working:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SAR_AddNewEmps_app]
AS
INSERT INTO dbo.PS_SAR_General ([USID], [Status], [ECS ICS], [Employee Class])
  SELECT PS_SAR_General.USID, PS_SAR_General.[Status]
    , PS_SAR_General.[ECS ICS], PS_SAR_General.[Employee Class]
  FROM dbo.PS_SAR_General
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT PS_Emp.[USID]
    FROM PS_Emp
    WHERE PS_SAR_General.[USID] = PS_Emp.[USID]
  ) AND [Status] = 'Active'
  AND [ECS ICS] = 'ECS'
  AND [Employee Class] NOT IN ('BRWDRESORCE', 'SUBCONTRACT')
```

This stored procedure adds now rows that didn't exist in the new table but exist in the employee table.